# Three.js: How to rotate an Object with Omega Phi Kappa

Tags: 3d, three.js, rotation

I have rotational data given in Omega Phi Kappa.
What is the correct way to rotate an object so it will be rotated correctly?

https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202558969-How-does-Pix4Dmapper-define-Omega-Phi-Kappa-#gsc.tab=0

Comment: what is Omega Phi Kappa?

Comment: @gaitat It is a way to represent rotations. I think in world Axis.:https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202558969-How-does-Pix4Dmapper-define-Omega-Phi-Kappa-#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Rotations around different axes are not interchangeable! This means the result depends on the order in which we apply these rotations. So you have to decide what is correct.